# How to include audio file in apk?

Tags: android

Iam a learner of creating android custom app. I create simple app using HTML files via Quick-App-v1.1. I have include the audio file in html file. it's properly play when open the HTML file in browsers, but when create the app the audio file not playing. Please advice me.

Answer (score 1):

Create a folder in Android Studio under 'res' and name it 'raw'.
Copy your audio file to the raw folder.

To play the audio file you can use something such as:

```
MediaPlayer song;

//then play it inside your onCreate
song = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.YOUR_SONG_NAME);
song.start();
```

Check this out:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

Comment: sorry i don't have android studio software. am creating the apk file with Quick-App-v1.1.